# Looping through a folder in python returning blank dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

I am trying to grab all the files located in the folder but for some reason the code is return blank data frame. Below is my code:

```
def fwd_pick(p):
    
    final2 = pd.DataFrame()
    
    excel_files2 = glob.glob(p + '.xlsx')
    
    for f in excel_files2:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(f)
        final2 = final2.append(df2)
        
    return final2

# Getting the forward pick locations
fwdpick = fwd_pick('C:/Users/abc/newfolder/')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I was about to leave a comment about how questions and answers should be separate. However, I figured it out yourself. *That was the reason for the rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I missed * in `glob.glob` that's why it was not reading properly. It works fine now.

```
def fwd_pick(p):
    
    final2 = pd.DataFrame()
    
    excel_files2 = glob.glob(p + '*.xlsx')
    
    for f in excel_files2:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(f)
        final2 = final2.append(df2)
        
    return final2

# Getting the forward pick locations
fwdpick = fwd_pick('C:/Users/abc/newfolder/')
```